# Getting a sub set of SortedDictionary as a SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, linq

In C# how do I filter a SortedDictionary using LINQ producing a subset which also is a SortedDictionary? Eg. I'd like to write

```
SortedDictionary<int, Person> source = ..fetch..
SortedDictionary<int, Person> filtered = source.Where(x=>x.foo == bar)
```

---

The only way I've found is to create a helper method and use that

```
SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> SubDictionary<TKey, TValue> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> l) 
{
    SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> result = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (var e in l)
      result[e.Key] = e.Value;
    return result;
}

...

SortedDictionary<int, Person> source = ..fetch..
SortedDictionary<int, Person> filtered = SubDictionary(source.Where(x=>x.foo == bar))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a one-statement solution, this will work:

```
SortedDictionary<int, Person> filtered = 
    new SortedDictionary<int, Person>(
        source.Where(x => x.Value.foo == bar)
              .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value));
```

However, it is inefficient, as it creates two dictionary objects (the ToDictionary() extension method creates one, which is then passed to the SortedDictionary constructor).

Your helper method will result in better performance. For cleaner syntax, you could make it an extension method on IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>:

```
public static class KeyValuePairEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> l)
    {
        SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> result = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var e in l) 
            result[e.Key] = e.Value;
        return result;
    }
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
var f2 = source.Where(x => x.Value.foo == bar).ToSortedDictionary();
```